# Windows ServerCore - HttpSendRequest ends in Operation aborted

Tags: docker, delphi, server-core

I have a .NET(x64) console application (RPC-Endpoint) programmed with Delphi running in a windows/servercore docker container. That RCP-Endpoint calls a soap interface in the background to gather some further data.
When I run this RPC-Endpoint on the servercore and the application tries to call the soap-endpoint, it stops with the error `Operation aborted` at `Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans.SOAPHTTPTrans.THTTPReqResp.Send`.

Now my guess is that something is wrong with the `WinINET` library on the servercore, because the Delphi SOAP-Client uses the `HttpSendRequest` function from the `WinApi.WinINET` library to call a SOAP-Endpoint.

Now my question is, is there any package that needs be installed on the windows/servercore so that the application can call an soap-endpoint without getting the `Operation aborted` error?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify!

Comment: I have revised my question so that it is a little clearer.

Comment: There is no such thing as *a .NET(x64) application programmed with Delphi*.